# Adding new columns to the CSV file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file that contains 5 columns and the number of lines varies.
I want to append three columns being populated from variables. The variable value stays the same.

At the moment I am doing it in the following way:

```
#!/bin/bash

newvar1="abcd6"
newvar2="abcd7"
newvar3="abcd8"

rm -rf *.txtyy
number_of_lines=`wc -l smallsample.txt|awk {'print $1'}`
for i in `seq $number_of_lines`; do
echo $newvar1 >> paste1.txtyy
echo $newvar2 >> paste2.txtyy
echo $newvar3 >> paste3.txtyy
done

paste -d "," smallsample.txt paste1.txtyy paste2.txtyy paste3.txtyy
```

Script output is:

```
# bash paste.sh
abcd1,abcd2,abcd3,abcd4,abcd5,abcd6,abcd7,abcd8
abcd1,abcd2,abcd3,abcd4,abcd5,abcd6,abcd7,abcd8
abcd1,abcd2,abcd3,abcd4,abcd5,abcd6,abcd7,abcd8
abcd1,abcd2,abcd3,abcd4,abcd5,abcd6,abcd7,abcd8
```

Execution time on 1,000,000 lines on my machine is:

```
time bash paste.sh

real    0m24.257s
user    0m14.668s
sys     0m9.380s
```

Input:

```
abcd1,abcd2,abcd3,abcd4,abcd5
abcd1,abcd2,abcd3,abcd4,abcd5
abcd1,abcd2,abcd3,abcd4,abcd5
abcd1,abcd2,abcd3,abcd4,abcd5
...
abcd1,abcd2,abcd3,abcd4,abcd5
```

Required output:

```
abcd1,abcd2,abcd3,abcd4,abcd5,abcd6,abcd7,abcd8
abcd1,abcd2,abcd3,abcd4,abcd5,abcd6,abcd7,abcd8
abcd1,abcd2,abcd3,abcd4,abcd5,abcd6,abcd7,abcd8
abcd1,abcd2,abcd3,abcd4,abcd5,abcd6,abcd7,abcd8
...
abcd1,abcd2,abcd3,abcd4,abcd5,abcd6,abcd7,abcd8
```

I believe that what am I doing here is such an overkill and wasting available resources. 
Can I do better and faster somehow on Debian 9.4 using available tools in that distro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could try something like this

```
#!/bin/bash

newvar1="abcd6"
newvar2="abcd7"
newvar3="abcd8"

awk -v var1="$newvar1" -v var2="$newvar2" -v var3="$newvar3" -vOFS="," '{print $0,var1,var2,var3}' smallsample.txt > outputfile.txt
```

I haven't tested its performance, but I think it shouldn't be so bad.

Comment: I suggest: `awk -v var1="$newvar1" -v var2="$newvar2" -v var3="$newvar3" -v OFS="," '{print $0,var1,var2,var3}' file`

Comment: Amazing! It yielded with this approach: time bash paste.sh

real    0m0.436s
user    0m0.224s
sys     0m0.208s

Comment: @Cyrus Yes, it is actually better and cleaner to use OFS than concatenate output with commas :) I'll edit the response for future references.

Comment: Also `-vvar=value` (no space after `-v`) is gawk-only, use `-v var=value` for portability. And, of course, always quote your shell variables - `-v var="$newvar1"` etc.

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try following. This will save output into Input_file itself.

```
cat script.ksh
newvar1="abcd6"
newvar2="abcd7"
newvar3="abcd8"

awk -v var1="$newvar1" -v var2="$newvar2" -v var3="$newvar3" 'BEGIN{OFS=","}{print $0,var1,var2,var3}' Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file input_file
```